# in Django,what is the best way to store a content which consist of images and text?

Tags: sql, django, database-design, django-database

I am building a website like a blog.
On my website, I am going to have an article with at least 4 paragraphs and also a minimum of 4 pictures. I am planning to use RichTextField for it but I am here to get advice from you experienced people. As I said, I am totally new to Django. What is the best and fastest way to store an article with images?
By the way, before I asked the question, I googled it but most questions came down to Django 2.0. There must be better ways now.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Harun Demirbaş if you are using your blog dashboard as django admin panel than RichTextField if best option for editing text and adding images. I will suggest you to add image CDN because it is easy as compare to uploading images to media still you want to upload images than check this URL https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#required-for-using-widget-with-file-upload
if you are not using django admin panel than here is the example for normal form
https://cdn.ckeditor.com/